# Paralelize mixed f77 f90 Fortran code?

Tags: multithreading, fortran, fortran90, gfortran, fortran77

I have a code written mostly in f77 however there are also routines written with the f90 syntax.

I've been reading how to use openMP for each case, but now I have the doubt how should I do it if I have both syntax in the same code?

More specifically should I use

```
  use omp_lib
```

or

```
  include 'omp_lib.h'
```

but in the same .f file I have both sintaxys. what if I use both?

I am compiling with gfortran 4.8.4.

If I use let's say

```
use omp_lib (meaning f90 syntax)
```

Then I have to use the correspondent syntax

```
!$omp parallel shared ( var1, var2 ) private ( i, j )

!$omp do
do j = 1, n
do i = 1, m
  var1(i,j) = var2
end do
end do
!$omp end do
```

However a few lines down I'll have a do loop written in f77

```
 c$omp parallel shared ( w ) private ( i, j )

 c$omp do
  do 20 i = 10, 1, -2
     write(*,*) 'i =', i
  20  continue
 c$omp end do
```

but this way to call the parallel loop would be recognised by using use omp_lib?

The same question when is the opposite.

Comment: I don't understand a word, but +1 for question about fortran :-)

Comment: Use tag [tag:fortran] as people mostly follow that one.

Comment: BTW,  your `c$omp` is not necessarily Fortran 77, or it doesn't have to be. It is in *fixed form*, but even Fortran 2008 can be in fixed form. You can use Fortran 90 and later features there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need the `use` or `include` only if you call OpenMP procedures. If you just have a couple of `!$omp` directives it is not needed.

You only need this, when you call a procedure like:

```
   call omp_set_num_threads(1)
```

or

```
   tid = omp_get_thread_num()
```

but not for the directives.

For Fortran 90 and later code (even in fixed form which looks like Fortran 77) use

```
use omp_lib
```

because the compiler is then better able to check if you call the functions properly (it has an explicit interface to them).

If the code is true Fortran 77 (and not just looking like it), you have to use the `include` although technically Fortran 77 doesn't even know that. It is a common non-standard extension to Fortran 77.

Comment: Nice!, I've added in the question some extra doubts, could you check it again please.

Comment: @Nikko As I wrote in the first paragraph, you don't need it in this case at all! But `use omp_lib` can be used in both cases if needed. But it is not needed just for the directives.

Comment: ok so, if I understood properly. I will just use omp_lib, and I will add !$omp parallel shared ( var1, var2 ) private ( i, j )
!$omp do
!$omp end do

To the loops even when they are written in f77 syntax. That will make the code use the other available cores, right? (is there a way to define the number of cores in a general way?)

Comment: Please, read it again, you DO NOT need `use omp_lib` at all. It doesn't harm, but it is better to know when you do need it. The directives must be in the right form (fixed or free, not Fortran 77 or 90 as you call them).

Comment: And another thing that worries me, the whole file must be consistently free form or fixed form, you cannot mix it in one file! Free form files are typically `.f90` and fixed are typically `.f`.

Comment: this is a flag to compile
FFLAGSDEBUG = -ffixed-form -ffixed-line-length-132 -O3 #-extend-source -debug extended -debug-parameters all -C -CB -g

Comment: That means it is fixed form. Your `C$OMP` or `!$omp` must always start at the fifth column. You must add `-fopenmp` to enable OpenMP.

Comment: OK I've tried but somethign mus be wrong. It is not working. I've used both ways, without calling as you said, and calling with call omp_set_num_threads(4)

The code can't even run more than 3 seconds then it is just stopped. But I can't see any error =/

Comment: This is the error I get. Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: @Nikko This is a different problem, ask a new question. Put the code which causes this error into that question. Be sure to compile with `-g -fbacktrace -fcheck=all -Wall` and report in the question the output. Also read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to help you to prepare a good code example.