# Openmp and Fortran, crashing code

Tags: fortran, openmp, gfortran

This is related to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35203586/paralelize-mixed-f77-f90-fortran-code). I am trying to parallelize a code with mixed syntax (f77 and f90)

I've added into one of the many routines this portion in the code

```
 !$omp parallel shared (xdif,cdiff, dg,bfvisc,r,ro,xm ) private ( l ) 
 !$omp do
 DO L=2,n-1
        xdif(l)=cdiff(l)*fjc+(dg(l)+bfvisc(l))*
 &           (4.d0*pi*r(l)**2*ro(l)/xm(n))**2

 ENDDO

 !$omp end do
 !$omp end parallel
```

After compiling (using `-fopenmp`) the code runs but just for a few seconds and the only error I'm getting is: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

I didn't use the module `omp_lib` (since that was suggested in an answer to the previous question) but I also try with it (using `call omp_set_num_threads(4)` before the first line). And both ways I have the same problem.

What can I do?

I've been advised also to print the output with the flags `-g -fbacktrace -fcheck=all -Wall`.  Here it is:

```
 At line 2828 of file mainII.f
 Fortran runtime error: Index '0' of dimension 1 of array 'l1mlos' below lower bound of 1
```

Comment: Your error can come from something that happens elsewhere : you are probably corrupting the memory *before* the openMP loop, but activating the openMP reveals the bug which stays silent in your "working" version.

Comment: I think you are right...I've updated the output and I am afraid that I'll have to change everything (which is the thing I don't want), because a lot of arrays have this kind of construction (index 0 ...)

Comment: thanks. And @AnthonyScemama, help?

Comment: hmmm.. Difficult to tell without having the full code! Your program seems to have a bug even if it doesn't crash in single threaded mode. Can you trust the results it gives? If you can, a workaround will be to define the array `l1mlos` starting at zero (like `l1mlos(0:nmax)`) : It will avoid to write somewhere where there is important data. Good luck

Comment: The conflictive line was  "if(irlof.ne.0.and.l1mlos(i1mlos).ne.0)" and i1mlos it is an integer which value is 0 or 10. I'll try with your workaround.

Comment: @AnthonyScemama I am sorry for this stupid question but can help me with this...when l1mlos is defined, it is written real(8) :: l1mlos(npl1) what exactly means that?

Comment: By the way I think you are right, the problem is that the code it is written with f77 and f90 syntax. So I have this problem not with just this variable. Is it possible another workaround?

Comment: You can also split your if statement in two statements : `if(irlof > 0) then if (l1mlos(i1mlos).ne.0) then ... end if end if`. Fortran does not guarantee the order in which `.and.` is performed.

Comment: Thanks Anthony, I am afraid I'll have to write the code again completely if I want to fix these issues. so all the arrays in the code are defined by a single integer. so the nomenclature was real(8) variable(alfa). So I thought if I define them again like real(8) variable(0:alfa-1) maybe I would avoid the problem (as you suggested), but now I've done and I have a completely new error... and I am sure that is because the way it is accessed to different array, this new declaration will mess up everything =/.

Comment: @AnthonyScemama as soon as I activate the -fopenmp flag, the code crashes (even when I fix the problem that I had before, I've redefine the variables when they where 0 or so.) I've tried also with this workaround, but without -fopenmp that the code works fine, but when I use it crashes, saying "Segmentation fault (core dumped) ps: I have always the flags -g -fbacktrace -fcheck=all -Wall.  included.